# What does this error mean? And how to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, migrate

I am trying to add models to the database and I am getting an error. Please explain what I am doing wrong.

```
dadi2015@ubuntu:~$ sudo python3 /home/allianceserver/myauth/manage.py migrate
[sudo] password for dadi2015: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allianceserver/myauth/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 13, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    if not (self.connection.sql_mode & {'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'}):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 376, in sql_mode
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `sudo`.

You can see in the error that the database is hitting permissions issues because the password you've provided for `mysql` is not correct for the user `root`. `sudo` tells the shell to run as the user `root`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem to access the database. First, make sure the user has permission. Secondly, use **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost**. I am not sure, but I faced similar problem and sorted out with this way.